# Nservicebus routing

Tags: nservicebus

We have multiple web and windows applications which were deployed to different servers that we are planning to integrate using NservierBus to let all apps can pub/sub message between them, I think we using pub/sub pattern and using MSMQ transport will be good for it. but one thing I am not clear if it is a way to avoid hard code to set sub endpoint to MSMQ QueueName@ServerName which has server name in it directly if pub is on another server. on 6-pre I saw idea to set endpoint name then using routing to delegate to transport-level address, is that a solution to do that? or only gateway is the solution? is a broker a good idea? what is the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried using the config files? http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-owner 

There's no way around somehow letting the subscriber know where it needs to look for it's subscribed message to create the correct subscription. I'd generally try to make sure you don't send messages to specific instances and let those simply subscribe to general events. It's quite a generic question and besides above configuration might fit better in Architecture or Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using pub/sub, the subscriber currently needs to know the location of the queue of the publisher. The subscriber then sends a subscription-message to that queue, every single time it starts up. It cannot know if it subscribed already and if it subscribed for all the messages, since you might have added/configured some new ones.

The publisher reads these subscriptions messages and stores the subscription in storage. NServiceBus does this for you, so there's no need to write code for this. The only thing you need is configuration in the subscriber as to where the (queue of the) publisher is.
I wrote a tutorial myself which you can find here : http://dennis.bloggingabout.net/2015/10/28/nservicebus-publish-subscribe-tutorial/

That being said, you should take special care related to issues regarding websites that publish messages. More information on that can be found here : http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications

In a scale out situation with MSMQ, you can also use the distributor : http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/scalability-and-ha/distributor/

As a final note: It depends on the situation, but I would not worry too much about knowing locations of endpoints (or their queues). I would most likely not use pub/sub just for this 'technical issue'. But again, it completely depends on the situation. I can understand that rich-clients which spawn randomly might want this. But there are other solutions as well, with a more centralized storage and an API that is accessed by all the rich clients.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, But if several subscribers need subscribe one message type from an publisher on serverA. if I put QueueName@ServeA in the config. but one day if I move publisher to serverB, it seems I need to go to every subscriber config to update all Queue endpoint, do we have a way to avoid this without using central storage?

Comment: All subscribers need to be notified & changed, so they can subscribe to the ServerB publisher. It's very common that subscribers also send other messages to publishers then just the subscription-message, so they need to know anyhow. After all subscription-messages have been sent to ServerB, you can turn ServerA off.

You can build something yourself bypassing config using this : http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-owner#configuring-endpoint-mapping